# Using file_get_contents and ftp_put

Tags: php

Is there a way we can use file_get_contents then ftp file upload the file fetched from file_get_contents to the remote site?

I have the code below but I am getting error:

```
<?php
ob_start();

$file = 'http://test4.*****.com/';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "John Smith\n";


$host = 'ftp.******.com';
$usr = '*******';
$pwd = '*******';        
$local_file = $current;
$ftp_path = 'test4/resources-test.php';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");     

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");
// perform file upload
ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/public_html/');
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);
if($upload) { $ftpsucc=1; } else { $ftpsucc=0; }
// check upload status:
print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
print "\n";
// close the FTP stream
ftp_close($conn_id);

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Below is all the error I'm getting:

```
Warning: ftp_put(<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

It cuts off after this...

Comment: And now we need to guess what error you have? Guys - you **need** to solve the issue, not we. So it's your obligation to give **all** the information in the question.

Comment: Warning <> = Error, Mr Choi, please re-consider a bit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ftp_put`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) expects a *path* to a local file as its third argument, not the *contents* of the file like you are passing it here:

```
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "John Smith\n";

...

$local_file = $current;

...

$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);
```

You will probably want to do something like this:

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fputs($fp, $current);
rewind($fp); // so that we can read what we just wrote in

// Using ftp_fput instead of ftp_put -- also, FTP_ASCII sounds like a bad idea
$upload = ftp_fput($conn_id, $ftp_path, $fp, FTP_BINARY);
fclose($fp); // we don't need it anymore
```