# Get screenshot from url2png and save to FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I am using url2png to get screenshots from pages. However, instead of asking the image every time, I want to save it onto an external server via FTP.

My first approach was to use:

```
$image = fopen($src,"r");
```

And then an ftp_fput. But as url2png may take about 5 secs to get the screenshot, the ftp_fput uploads an empty file.

Do I need to save the file locally first? or is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using this question: [Using file_get_contents and ftp_put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386117/using-file-get-contents-and-ftp-put)

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fputs($fp, file_get_contents($src));
rewind($fp);
```